# Functor with std::for_each in C++

Tags: c++, functor

This is the functor code that I copied from http://www.catonmat.net/blog/on-functors/.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class EvenOddFunctor {
    int even_;
    int odd_;
public:
    EvenOddFunctor() : even_(0), odd_(0) {}
    void operator()(int x) {
        if (x%2 == 0) even_ += x;
        else odd_ += x;
    }
    int even_sum() const { return even_; }
    int odd_sum() const { return odd_; }
};

int main() {
    EvenOddFunctor evenodd;

    int my_list[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    // ??? why assign 
    evenodd = std::for_each(my_list,
                  my_list+sizeof(my_list)/sizeof(my_list[0]),
                  evenodd); // ???

    std::cout << "Sum of evens: " << evenodd.even_sum() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Sum of odds: " << evenodd.odd_sum() << std::endl;

    // output:
    // Sum of evens: 30
    // Sum of odds: 25
}
```

Why do we need assigning the value back to `evanodd` object after the operation as in `evenodd = std::for_each(my_list,`? I thought that as the evenodd object is updated from the std::for_each, I don't need the assignment operation, but without this assignment, the results show 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::for_each` accepts the functor by value, that means it modifies a local copy. The assignment gets that local copy back so you can actually see the modified version.

This is important as your functor has mutable state that you are interested in, in particular `evenodd.even_sum` and `evenodd.odd_sum`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do a few experiments.

First, try not to assign it, see what happens. After you tried it, if you figured it out, there's no need to read any further, so you can stop.

If you couldn't figure it out, let's make a second experiment, and change the relevant parts of your `main()` as follows:

```
const EvenOddFunctor evenodd_orig;

int my_list[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
// ??? why assign
auto evenodd = std::for_each(my_list,
              my_list+sizeof(my_list)/sizeof(my_list[0]),
              evenodd_orig); // ???
```

The key part here is that you're passing a *constant* object to `std::for_each`. This will compile, but if `std::for_each` worked the way you *think* it works, this shouldn't compile.

After all, the `operator()` is *not* a constant method, so with `std::for_each` getting a const reference, it shouldn't be able to call your mutable `operator()` method.

And that's because what's essentially happening is that `std::for_each` makes an internal copy of the functor that you're passing to it. It takes its functor parameter by value, not by reference, and your functor ends up modifying its internal state.

That's why `std::for_each` returns the functor object when it's done, and that's why you need to store it, because the original object, that was passed to `std::for_each` has not been modified!